# Child window doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, custom-events

I'm trying to add a custom event listener to this object:

```
openWindows[_id].window.addEventListener('onChildReady', function (event) {
        if (params.title) {
          openWindows[_id].window.document.title = params.title;
        }
      }, true);
```

where `openWindows[_id].window` is a reference to a pop-up window opened from this window.

It doesn't work on IE11, it gives this exception on console:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
   at open (/path/to/app.min.js:54209:7)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you detecting that the popup is already fully loaded? Compare with trying to write to the popup body without checking that the document.body is already available. All same-origin rules still apply.

Comment: 'onChildReady' event is emitted when the popup is fully loaded

Comment: Yes, but is the window fully loaded when you try to add the event listener? When I try to write to window.document.body of a popup without checking if the body is available, it fails half of the time as well due to timing issues. onload handlers and such don't always work. So I just use an interval until window.addEventListener returns a function and document.body selector returns a node so I'm explicitly sure that the popup is ready.

Comment: I'm not writing on the body. I'm just adding an event to the window.

Comment: Hence I'm asking if you check if the addEventListener function is available already...

Comment: I added a setinterval, and it actually works. Thank you

Comment: Glad that solved your problem. Good luck and have fun. Don't forget to clear the interval after. ;)